# Conditions of Convergence of complex series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $S$ is a complex series. If we want to show $S$ to be convergent, then it is sufficient to show $\mid S\mid$ is convergent. Why is this true? Why arg$(S)$ is not playing any role?

Comment: $|\sum_{k-n}^{m} a_k| \leq \sum_{k-n}^{m} |a_k| \to 0$ as $n, m \to \infty$.

Comment: Maybe think about the following (simplest) situation : a complex *sequence* $(u_n)$ converges to $0$ if and only if the real sequence $(|u_n|)$ converges to $0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I understand what you say, but why we are concerned about the modulus of the series is my question.. After that how to proceed is clear to me..

Comment: As mentioned by TheSIlverDoe convergence of a sequence of complex numbers to $0$ depends only on the modulus, not on the argument. If one number $c$ is close to $0$ then all numbers on the circle with center $0$ and radius $|c|$ are also close to $0$.

Comment: @roydiptajit Maybe you can think on a geometric way : a sequence of complex numbers is converging to another complex number if the points that represent these numbers in the plan are approaching the point representing the limit. The only thing that counts is the fact that the distance between them tends to $0$ (i.e. the modulus), and not the fact that they are turning or not turning around the limit while approaching it.

Comment: Yes, I got this from your comment, but I cannot formalize it via triangle inequality..Can you help..@TheSilverDoe

Comment: @roydiptajit There is no triangle inequality here, this is just the definition of convergence. By definition, a complex sequence $(u_n)$ converges to $l$ if $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall n \geq N$, $|u_n-l| \leq \varepsilon$. See that the modulus is already present in the definition, it does not take the argument into account.

Comment: This is the definition for complex sequence.. Can we generalize this for complex series too? I am confused about what happens in a series

Comment: @roydiptajit The convergence of a series $\sum u_k$ is just the convergence of the sequence $(\sum_{k=0}^n u_k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. So a series is a particular case of a sequence.

Comment: Okay thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comment that got too long and which tries to explain various things involved above.

In general, the statement in the OP is ambiguous and under a reasonable interpretation is not even true. So to make it clear let $S_n=\sum_{k \le n} a_n$ the partial sums of the series, $T_n = \sum_{k \le n} |a_n|$ the partial sums of the series with absolute value terms.

So if we interpret the OP as $|S_n|$ converges implies the series converges, the result is not true in general as taking $a_n$ (which are $S_n-S_{n-1}, S_{-1}=0$ say) st $S_n=e^{2\pi i \sqrt 2 n}, n \ge 0$ shows as $|S_n|=1$ but obviously $S_n$ doesn't converge and it is actually a dense sequence in the unit circle

If we interpret the OP as $T_n$ converges, then the result is true but then the series is absolutely convergent which is a very strong form of convergence.

On the other hand, if $|S_n| \to 0$ or more generally if $|S_n-L| \to 0$ for some complex $L$, then indeed the series converges to zero or $L$ respectively and that is a possible correct interpretation of the OP.

So as to the question asked, the argument actually matters unless we have strong conditions like absolute convergence or we interpret the statement as the third choice above

Comment: So, absolute value of series convergence does not tell anything about the original series correct? Then my interpretation was wrong.. That is why I was confused with the argument..

Comment: unless the series sums to zero, when $S_n \to 0$ is equivalent to $|S_n| \to 0$ as then the argument doesn't matter (after all $0$ has no uniquely defined argument)